# Broadcast a channel through multiple channel in Go

Tags: go, channel

I would like to broadcast data received from a channel to a list of channel. The list of channel is dynamic an can be modified during the run phase.

As a new developper in `Go`, I wrote this code. I found it quite heavy for what I want. Is-there a better way to do this?

```
package utils

import "sync"

// StringChannelBroadcaster broadcasts string data from a channel to multiple channels
type StringChannelBroadcaster struct {
    Source      chan string
    Subscribers map[string]*StringChannelSubscriber
    stopChannel chan bool
    mutex       sync.Mutex
    capacity    uint64
}

// NewStringChannelBroadcaster creates a StringChannelBroadcaster
func NewStringChannelBroadcaster(capacity uint64) (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) {
    return &StringChannelBroadcaster{
        Source:      make(chan string, capacity),
        Subscribers: make(map[string]*StringChannelSubscriber),
        capacity:    capacity,
    }
}

// Dispatch starts dispatching message
func (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) Dispatch() {
    b.stopChannel = make(chan bool)
    for {
        select {
        case val, ok := <-b.Source:
            if ok {
                b.mutex.Lock()
                for _, value := range b.Subscribers {
                    value.Channel <- val
                }
                b.mutex.Unlock()
            }
        case <-b.stopChannel:
            return
        }
    }
}

// Stop stops the Broadcaster
func (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) Stop() {
    close(b.stopChannel)
}

// StringChannelSubscriber defines a subscriber to a StringChannelBroadcaster
type StringChannelSubscriber struct {
    Key     string
    Channel chan string
}

// NewSubscriber returns a new subsriber to the StringChannelBroadcaster
func (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) NewSubscriber() *StringChannelSubscriber {
    key := RandString(20)
    newSubscriber := StringChannelSubscriber{
        Key:     key,
        Channel: make(chan string, b.capacity),
    }
    b.mutex.Lock()
    b.Subscribers[key] = &newSubscriber
    b.mutex.Unlock()

    return &newSubscriber
}

// RemoveSubscriber removes a subscrber from the StringChannelBroadcaster
func (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) RemoveSubscriber(subscriber *StringChannelSubscriber) {
    b.mutex.Lock()
    delete(b.Subscribers, subscriber.Key)
    b.mutex.Unlock()
}
```

Thank you,

Julien

Comment: Sometimes go code feels "heavy" because there are no syntactic sugar wrappers around low level operations.  This seems like a normal approach to me; what would you want to see "lighter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify it a bit: get rid of `stopChannel` and the `Stop` method. You can just close `Source` instead of calling Stop, and detect that in `Dispatch` (ok will be false) to quit (you can just range over the source channel actually).

You can get rid of `Dispatch`, and just start a goroutine in `NewStringChannelBroadcaster` with the for cycle, so external code doesn't have to start the dispatch cycle separately.

You can use a channel type as the map key, so your map can become `map[chan string]struct{}` (empty struct because you don't need the map value). So your `NewSubscriber` can take a channel type parameter (or create a new channel and return it), and insert that into the map, you don't need the random string or the `StringChannelSubscriber` type.

I also made some improvements, like closing the subscriber channels:

```
package main

import "sync"

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// StringChannelBroadcaster broadcasts string data from a channel to multiple channels
type StringChannelBroadcaster struct {
    Source      chan string
    Subscribers map[chan string]struct{}
    mutex       sync.Mutex
    capacity    uint64
}

// NewStringChannelBroadcaster creates a StringChannelBroadcaster
func NewStringChannelBroadcaster(capacity uint64) *StringChannelBroadcaster {
    b := &StringChannelBroadcaster{
        Source:      make(chan string, capacity),
        Subscribers: make(map[chan string]struct{}),
        capacity:    capacity,
    }
    go b.dispatch()
    return b
}

// Dispatch starts dispatching message
func (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) dispatch() {
    // for iterates until the channel is closed
    for val := range b.Source {
        b.mutex.Lock()
        for ch := range b.Subscribers {
            ch <- val
        }
        b.mutex.Unlock()
    }
    b.mutex.Lock()
    for ch := range b.Subscribers {
        close(ch)
        // you shouldn't be calling RemoveSubscriber after closing b.Source
        // but it's better to be safe than sorry
        delete(b.Subscribers, ch)
    }
    b.Subscribers = nil
    b.mutex.Unlock()
}

func (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) NewSubscriber() chan string {
    ch := make(chan string, b.capacity)
    b.mutex.Lock()
    if b.Subscribers == nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("NewSubscriber called on closed broadcaster"))
    }
    b.Subscribers[ch] = struct{}{}
    b.mutex.Unlock()

    return ch
}

// RemoveSubscriber removes a subscrber from the StringChannelBroadcaster
func (b *StringChannelBroadcaster) RemoveSubscriber(ch chan string) {
    b.mutex.Lock()
    if _, ok := b.Subscribers[ch]; ok {
        close(ch)                 // this line does have to be inside the if to prevent close of closed channel, in case RemoveSubscriber is called twice on the same channel
        delete(b.Subscribers, ch) // this line doesn't need to be inside the if
    }
    b.mutex.Unlock()
}

func main() {
    b := NewStringChannelBroadcaster(0)

    var toberemoved chan string

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        i := i

        ch := b.NewSubscriber()
        if i == 1 {
            toberemoved = ch
        }
        go func() {
            for v := range ch {
                fmt.Printf("receive %v: %v\n", i, v)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Exit %v\n", i)
        }()
    }

    b.Source <- "Test 1"
    b.Source <- "Test 2"
    // This is a race condition: the second reader may or may not receive the first two messages.
    b.RemoveSubscriber(toberemoved)
    b.Source <- "Test 3"

    // let the reader goroutines receive the last message
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    close(b.Source)

    // let the reader goroutines write close message
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/X-NcikvbDM

Edit: I've added your edit to fix the panic when calling `RemoveSubscriber` after closing `Source`, but you shouldn't be doing that, you should let the struct and everything in it be garbage collected after the channel is closed.
I've also added a panic to `NewSubscriber` if it's called after closing `Source`. Previously you could do that and it'd leak the created channel and presumably the goroutine that will block forever on that channel.

If you can call `NewSubscriber` (or `RemoveSubscriber`) on an already closed broadcaster, that probably means there's an error in your code somewhere, since you're holding on to a broadcaster that you shouldn't be.